# Google rich snippet looks different then Google Search

Tags: google, google-search-console, rich-snippets

I have added the authorship to a website of mine however it looks like [this](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http://christina-cannon.com/) when I enter my URL into the tool, however when I search for the site on Google, it shows an out of date cached image and doesn't appear like the rich snippet tool. Any insight as to why this is happening?

Comment: How long has it been since you have updated it?  It might need time to update, what is the date of the Google cache of the page?

Comment: @moobot It has been 3 days since I updated the page. The as cached version of the page is Jun 12, 2013.

Comment: Wait until Google has updated its cache.of the page with the current changes,maybe it will display correct then.

Answer (score 1):

Rich Snippets only show if you're logged into Google+ or at least Authorship Rich Snippets only show if you're logged into Google+.  It also depends what keywords were typed into the search.

Rich Snippets aren't guaranteed, sometimes Google for a keyword phrase might not show them when for a different keyword phrase they will show a Rich Snippet. There is a difference between "Rich Snippets" and Authorship.  Authorship is tied to Google+, Rich Snippets are tied to schema.org and a few other standards.

Supposedly Amazon.com doesn't follow any of the recommended standard but Googlebot knows how their website works so they get "Rich Snippets" anyway. **It is good to be the king of e-commerce.**